# The returned list from ajax is empty but the size of the array is correct

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a List from the controller to an ajax function, which I need to show a modal carousel images.

The function start when I click on a image, send a value to the ajax function, the ajax function calls a C# method in the controller, and in return I expect to have a List of paths of the images I'm showing.

This is the Html where the function starts:

```
<div class="columnaPedido mb-3">
      <img class="imgPedido" src="@pd.getImagenes()" onclick="GetImagenes(@pd.getNumeroEntrega())" data-img-mostrar="@cont" />
</div>
```

This is the ajax function:

```
function GetImagenes(entrega){
    var i = 0;
    console.log(entrega);
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "GetPedidoImagenes",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'entrega': entrega },        
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("Longitud: " + result.length);            
            if (result == 0) {
                alert("No hay Imagenes");
            }
            else {
                while (i < result.length) {
                    console.log(result.count);
                    var carusel = document.getElementById("Entrega_" + entrega);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100');
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', "/imgAndroid/" + result[i].Path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100');
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', "/imgAndroid/" +  result[i].Path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
     
            }
        }
    })
};
```

And this is the C# Controller method:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public List<PedidoViewModel> GetPedidoImagenes(string entrega)
 {
            string consulta;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
            MySqlConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                consulta = "SELECT Path from Entrega WHERE Entrega = '" + entrega + "'";
                using (connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";"))
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
                    connection.Open();

                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        PedidoViewModel pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                        pedido.setPathImagen(reader["Path"].ToString());
                        listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                    }
                }
                return listaPedidos;

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

This is `PedidoViewModel`:

```
[Keyless]
    public class PedidoViewModel{
      private string pathIamgenes;

      public PedidoViewModel(){
        pathIamgenes = "";
      }

     public string getImagenes() { return pathIamgenes; }
     public void setPathImagen(string x) { pathIamgenes = x; }
    }
```

As you can see, I pass a value from the view to the ajax function, and then from the ajax to the controller, and in return I have a list with tha paths, but the array (which is called
`result`) is empty, but has the right size.

What do I mean with the "right size"? If there are 2 images, `result` has 2 places, or 2 size.
How I checked this? with a `console.log(result)`:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{}
1:{}
```

But as you can see, the array is empty, and I'm expecting to have the paths of the images.

Where I am wrong? I been working for days with this and I can't find a solution.

I'm new with Javascript and ajax, I don't have lot of knowledge, but I think that what I'm doing is not wrong at all.

**Edit**

I created a `public string path{get; set;}` in `PedidoViewModel` and now `console.log(result)` comes like this:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{path: null}
1:{path: null}
```

new `PedidoViewModel`:

```
[Keyless]
 public class PedidoViewModel{
     public string path{get; set;} = "";
  }
```

Comment: There is no most important code ... `PedidoViewModel` ... if it doesnt contain any serializable fields/properties than `{}` json is pretty valid for it ...

Comment: Unrelated, but this is a bad idea: `throw new Exception(ex.Message);`  You're discarding all other useful information about the exception and replacing it with an entirely new one that contains *only the message* and nothing else.  Just remove the try/catch entirely and let the *original* exception surface.

Comment: @Selvin I edited the post...I didn't write the code but I think that in C# is not necessary to have that getPath() and setPath()...

Comment: hmm java's background? in C# we are using properties not setters/getters ... private fields would not be serialized(unless(prolly - depends on serializer) you are marking them for serialization) ... also json usage in javascript is `instance.property` rather then `instance.getProperty()`

Comment: @David I know, what I'm doing now is to save the `ex.message` and send to a custom Error View to show the message, is that correct?

Comment: @BilbitBolson: Showing an exception message to the user isn't a good idea either, it can reveal information about the system that an attacker could use against you.  You can certainly intercept that an exception occurred and show the user an error page.  But (1) don't show the actual exception to the user and (2) don't discard the original exception, log it somewhere so you can use it to identify and correct the problem.

Comment: Thank you @David, I will implement what you explained me, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class doesn't have any serializable properties:

```
public class PedidoViewModel{
  private string pathIamgenes;

  public PedidoViewModel(){
    pathIamgenes = "";
  }

  public string getImagenes() { return pathIamgenes; }
  public void setPathImagen(string x) { pathIamgenes = x; }
}
```

It has a *field* and has *methods* for interacting with that field.  But in general serializers are looking for *properties*.  (As are ORMs, etc.  Properties are the standard in C#.)

Refactor your class to use properties, which significantly simplies it anyway:

```
public class PedidoViewModel{
  public string PathIamgenes { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Then that one property would be serialized in the JSON:

```
{
  "PathIamgenes": ""
}
```

Naturally, *the rest* of the code which uses this class would need to be adjusted to make use of its new structure.